# finding or "compressing" similar rows in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table where every row has a "`group_id`" column. I would like to get a "compressed" output of all rows from that group as a single line (or more concise structure of any sort - not critical how it looks). This line is for applicative use only and not to be saved in the db. Since the table is very big , it will be very expensive to calculate on my own. I am willing to pre-calculate this value and cache it. I don't plan to calculate on the fly after that point.

In the "compressed" representation I don't care which values belong to which keys. I just want to get all the options up front for a given `group_id`.

For instance a subset of my table looks like this:

```
primary_key, group_id, column_a, column_b, column_c
key1, g1, a, b, c
key2, g1, a, b_1, c
key3, g1, a_1, b, c
key4, g2, a, b, c
key5, g2, a, b, c
key6, g3, x, y, z
key7, g3, x_1, y_1, z_1
key8, g3, x_2, y_2, z_3
```

A great result would be along the lines of

```
g1, a & a_1, b & b_1, c
g2, a, b, c
g3, x & x_1 & x_2, y & y_1 & y_2, z & z_1 & z_2
```

It's like a `GROUP BY` on all columns aggregating all possible results to a single row for the `group_id` column

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: perfect! answer and will except!

Answer (score 0):

Per gordon comment,

just need to do :

```
SELECT group_id, group_concat(DISTINCT column_a), group_concat(distinct column_b), group_concat(distinct column_c) 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY group_id
```